# Javascript - Get Element By Class & files[0]

Tags: javascript, file-upload, this

So i am trying to grab an element by the class and then store File[0].  I am trying to then use the files[0] function to then process a file upload.  When i do the following I get the error: "field.files is undefined" in my firebug console.

```
document.querySelector('#afile').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
var field = document.getElementsByClassName('File');
var file = field.files[0];
```

When I change my code to the following it works

```
document.querySelector('#afile').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
var file = this.files[0];
```

So I think the issue is with var file = field.files[0]. I need to grab this by class name and not "this".  Can someone please help me grab the element using class name instead of "this".  Thank you.

Comment: Classname returns a nodelist use fields[0].files. Where 0 is the first element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var field = document.getElementsByClassName('File');
var file = field[0].files[0];
```

As I commented. `getElementsByClassName()` returns a nodelist. SLaks said it also. It's an arrayish object. You can access it members like a regular array by index. `nodelist[index]`.

This is logical if you think about it. Classnames can be used by multiple elements. So when you select via this method it logical to expect multiple results.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName()` is plural.
It returns an array of elements.
You need to get an item from this array.